# Override follow label on LinkedIn Follow button

Tags: html, plugins, linkedin-api

I'm using [Linkedin Follow Company plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/follow-company-plugin)

and I jave defined the language (Danish) by doing this

```
<script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: da_DK</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="1337" data-counter="bottom"></script>
```

But it can't output the "Ø" in Følg, but instead outputs a weird character:

[image: Weird character]

Anyone know if the label is overridable somehow or could provide a solution?

Comment: DId you ever have any success with this? Having the same problem with Swedish

Comment: Unfortunately no :(